# Limit the people picker control according to contact list of each subsite

Tags: jquery, people-picker

We are using SP2016 on-premise. A custom people picker is setup according to [MSDN article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in?redirectedfrom=MSDN). The people picker control is working and we want to limit the picker selection according to a list (contract) within the same subsite.

May I know how can I work it out?

Comment: Do you mean you have users name/email id in a list an you want only those to show up in your people picker?

Comment: @harshalgite yes, exactly. User have permission to add user in the list but do not have permission to add SP group members.

Comment: ideally this should be done using OOTB way which is - a group and restricting people picker to chose users from that group only.